# SpringBoot LocaleChangeInterceptor not working before login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured Spring Boot with security and i18n. LocaleChangeInterceptor not working before I login.I want to change language on login screen as well depend upon user browser local.

/* Localization section is started */

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    registry.addInterceptor(new WebInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
    return new CookieLocaleResolver();
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    ret.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    ret.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return ret;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
  CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
  filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
  filter.setForceEncoding(true);
  return filter;
}
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot so your configuration is basically doing the same as the Spring Boot configuration. The `LocaleChangeInterceptor` will indeed not work because Spring Security will be triggered before the `DispatcherServlet` and thus before the point that interceptors kick in.

Comment: Any Solution ??

Comment: If you able to share your project on GitHub/Bitbucket/etc it would be helpful. I've successfully solved a bit similar problem (errors from spring-security weren't localized) but I used `SessionLocaleResolver`.

Comment: just for people (and me) who might have the same problem approximately and come to this question... as far as I see, locale contains two parts: language and country. I have seen that sometimes specifically the country part gets converted to lower-case on some servers. I never understood why. So my lesson to myself is to not use the country part, whenever I can avoid it. E.g. use el instead of el_GR or el-GR, so the corresponding message file would be messages_el.properties - otherwise in case locale case is changed, the proper messages file might not be found because it is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot 2.x, please add these configurations to application.properties

```
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=accept_header
spring.mvc.locale=en
```

To change the locale for the request add this Accept-Language to Http Request Header like

```
Accept-Language : en_US
```